# Consider the heat equation Cauchy problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the Cauchy problem
>   $$\begin{cases}
> u_{t}-u_{xx}=0 \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty\lt x\lt +\infty , t\gt0\\
> u(x,0)=\sin x  \ \    \\
> \end{cases}$$

I was doing like this :
$$u=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}\sin y \text dy $$ 
After the substitution $m=\frac{x-y}{2\sqrt{t}}$ , I get $$u=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{\pi }} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-m^2}\sin (2\sqrt t m+x) \text dm $$
 Now I can't move forward. How to simplify this or is there any problem in applying the formula.

Comment: Try writing $\sin x$ as the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying the fundamental solution (which should work using the hint given above), you can also use that the initial conditions are periodic and solve the equation using a Fourier series ansatz $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(t) \sin(nx)$. You then get an ODE for $a_n(t)$ that is easily solved (and because of your initial conditions, all but $a_1(t)$ are identically zero. The answer you get from this is $u(t)=e^{-t}\sin x$, which is the unique bounded solution.